# Application of Schur's Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-equations, matrices

Given three matrices , $B_1 \in Mat_{n_1}(k)$, $B_2 \in Mat_{n_2}(k)$, and  $C \in Mat_{n_1 \times n_2}(k)$, where $k$ is a perfect field, and $B_1 $ and $B_2$ are irreducible matrices. 
Required to show that there exists a matrix $X$ such that $$C+B_1X-XB_2=0$$
The given hint is to use Schur's lemma, however I try hardly but till now no sensible proof I can construct, any help would be highly appreciated.
 NOTE: what I mean by an irreducible matrix, is that its representing a linear map $f$ on a finite dimensional vector space that has no proper   $f$ invariant subspaces.

Comment: http://aero-comlab.stanford.edu/Papers/jameson_007.pdf

Comment: just google matrix equation ax-xb = c, there're lot more